# ,Net Entity Framework record Navigation

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I was wondering does the .Net Entity Framework allow you to initially load a Web form with the first record that is present in a table. And subsequently display the remaining records present in an entity or table in the same form, with the click of a button or record navigator.  A lot like  how Microsoft Access record navigation works. I want a Master child relationship where when you navigate to a parent record I will have a partial view that shows the child records. Thanks for any advice or recommendations.

Comment: Yes, it can do this.

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me to get started. Thanks !

Comment: Follow an Entity Framework tutorial to get started.  Most EF tutorials also involve MVC.

Comment: Are you saying that I should use MVC as per my use case?

Comment: I was not making that suggestion.

Comment: My 2 cents would be not to get locked into Windows GUI stuff. The web is a different paradigm. Showing stuff in a table/grid with paging and various jquery functionality is pretty boilerplate stuff.

Comment: What would not be considered boilerplate stuff? It must not be something that is easy to do because I have searched all over youtube for a video that explains a solution like this and I could not find one. Well I did find "one" and it didnt work.

Comment: In my opinion it would be an excellent start or foundation to understanding how to create database solutions that fit many different scenarios of user requirements.

Comment: Start with the basics and take things one piece at a time.  It's the only way to learn.

Comment: I am trying to build a master  partial child form using the entity framework, linq, jquery, and bootstrap. I dont think thats basic. I havent received any help with it so it couldnt be to basic. This is a production grade requirement.

Comment: Your question is so broad, it read like you don't have much experience programming.  Is that not the case?  I meant no insult.

Comment: Thats the problem I have a lot of experience as a developer. You never heard of a master child form? When you selct the next button it shows a  record and its child records? Whats broad about that? Thats a very common use case in a database development project. I have been programming since visual basic 3.0.

Comment: Yes, I have heard of a master child form.  Your question is broad because it lacks specifics.  Getting data out of a DB using EF is a pretty basic usage of EF.  Any EF tutorial will cover this, and most EF tutorials show how to connect EF data all the way from the database to the UI.  That you ask if EF can get a single record from a table is telling that the basics of EF are not understood.

Comment: But I was asking how do you click a next button and "repopulate" the form with the next record in the table or entity. As well as go out and grab the child records based on the master records primary key.

Comment: You understand now?

Comment: Once I get this done Im off to the races. Then I can shape my data to look how ever I want. But I guess this would be a design pattern that has been used for many years. I am just asking this forum how to do it with the Enity Framework ORM. But I think Im figuring it out.

Comment: I can recommend some reading that may shed some light this and help you refine your question further?  Look at "RESTful web services" using either Web API or MVC.  Either can be used to create a web service, but Web API is more specialized at it and you have more control.  To be honest, based on your last few comments, your question doesn't seem to be about EF at all.  jQuery has some plugins to facilitate paging a table.

Comment: Why restful webservice? why would I use a webservice just to pull data into my webform from entity framework? restful is server technology to facilitate the communication between different apps. The scope of this functionality is not broad enough to need rest.

Comment: MVC is a framework and a webservice is a transfer protocol????????

Comment: I'm not using a repository at this time until I can get the functionality working. Maybe thats what you are getting at, I dont know.

Comment: ... a web service lets your server communicate with the client.  If you're making a web page, I assume you want that.

Comment: Well I tried to help.  Good luck to you.